# Comment or uncomment particular line using bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file that contains

```
coffe
milk
water
etc..
```

I want to comment out one line, e.g., `milk` using a variable that contains `milk` or  `#milk`.

I'm trying to use `#` as switch.

```
checkval="milk"
```

When I use

```
sed 's/^.//' $file
```

this remove the first character on all lines.

When I use

```
sed -e "s/$checkval/\#$checkval/g" $file
```

this works by adding `#`.

I expect the following output file when the variable contains the value `#milk`:

```
coffe
milk
water
```

The expected output when the variable contains the value `milk`:

```
coffe
#milk
water
```

Comment: Try  https://ideone.com/k7M3b7

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please post that as an answer (where it can be voted on) instead of a comment with an external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below script will do the required tasks.

```
checkval="#milk"
initial="$(echo $checkval | head -c 1)"
if  [ "$initial" = "#" ] 
then
new_checkval="${checkval:1}"
sed -e 's_'$checkval'_'$new_checkval'_g' input.txt
else
sed -e 's_'$checkval'_#&_g' input.txt
fi
```

If the `checkval` is `milk` and the word `milk` is present in the file then it will be replaced by `#milk`. Similarly, If the `checkval` is `#milk` and the word `#milk`is present in the file, it will be replaced with `milk`.

Comment: Of course this script do required task! My mistake in other files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @miszczu you are welcome. I am glad it helped. If it really helped, you may upvote or accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: yes, i know, but unfortunetly i'm fresh user & got message: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @miszczu Oh i see. Thank you. Maybe, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may use an `if` condition to check if the `checkval` starts with a `#` char and implement different logic:

- If the `checkval` starts with `#`, you need to run the `sed` command using the `checkval` in the LHS as is and use the `${checkval:1}` (`checkval` without the first character) in the RHS
- Else, you need to search for `checkval` and replace it with `#` and the text found.

Consider using

```
checkval="milk";
if [[ $checkval != \#* ]]; then
  sed "s/$checkval/#&/" file > newfile
else
  sed "s/$checkval/${checkval:1}/" file > newfile
fi;
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/sclXDm) and [this demo, too](https://ideone.com/k7M3b7).

**NOTE**: If your search phrases can contain any chars, consider [escaping the patterns appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reply. I try both solution, and both works, but not as expected. I think I mixed up a little bit... My fault, sorry.
I have file:

```
coffe
milk
water
```

and the checkval contains `milk`
I suppose the output file will have like this:

```
coffe
#milk
water
```

In the second case
file contains:

```
coffe
#milk
water
```

checkval: `#milk`
output file will be:

```
coffe
milk
water
```

I trying to deny conditions , but this not work.